# Certificate issues at OpenVZ Ubuntu containers

Tags: ubuntu, ssl-certificate, openvz

today I came up with the problem that certificates cannot be verified on my openvz ubuntu containers. I checked the /etc/ssl/certs folder which is readable and seems to be ok.

However, when I try to use wget, I get the following:

```
$ wget https://google.com
--2014-01-29 11:05:16--  https://google.com/
Resolving google.com (google.com)... 173.194.112.194, 173.194.112.197, 173.194.112.195, ...
Connecting to google.com (google.com)|173.194.112.194|:443... connected.
ERROR: The certificate of `google.com' is not trusted.
ERROR: The certificate of `google.com' hasn't got a known issuer.
The certificate's owner does not match hostname `google.com'
```

I found the `--no-check-certificate` option which downloads at least the file, but doesn't solve the issue of accepting the certificate.

I also tried the `--ca-directory=/etc/ssl/certs`option which returns the same result.

Any ideas where the problem might be, or where I can start to troubleshoot?

Comment: You may try to run `update-ca-certificates`, your certificates are probably out of date (especially if you are using "official" ubuntu appliance.

Answer (score 1):

I've actually had this problem for a while myself.

It looks like the ca-certificates package is damaged in the Ubuntu container template from the OpenVZ project. I got it working by purging the package and re-installing as per this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/428152/134756

It worked out to this:

```
sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends ca-certificates
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates
```